# Android Calendar example

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar

i'm trying to use material Calendar view library https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview in my app.
The problem is that I need to create the Calendar View in a Fragment and on date click I need to create another Fragment related to the selected date. Can anyone do an example for this?

Comment: You have to show what you tried and we will then help you.  Provide the requirements and your approach.

Answer (score 0):

It shows Calendar but the Click Listener not work

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    private MaterialCalendarView calendarView;

    public CalendarFragment() {
        FragmentsUtils.addFragment(this, "Calendar", "Calendario ricordi", 
            null, R.id.content_main_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, 
            false);

        calendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

        calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {

            @Override
             public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView 
                 widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {

             Log.e("DAY", "DAY:" + date);
            }
        });

    return calendarView;
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```